# Mechanize work with javascript window.open in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, mechanize

I'm using `Mechanize` to crawl web and I get problem with `window.open`
Page has html like below:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.asp">
  <a href="javascript:yoyaku('0','main','https://example.com/xyz/')" class= "col">
    <span class="font-M1b">Click link</span>
  </a>
</form>
```

Page object in `mechanize` like:

```
[1] pry(#<Crawler::Inzai>)> agent.page
=> #<Mechanize::Page
 ...
 {links
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Click link" "javascript:yoyaku('0','main','https://example.com/xyz/')">
 {forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
   {name "form1"}
   {method "POST"}
   {action "index.asp"}
   {fields [hidden:0x4399a00 type: hidden name: MENULINK value: ] [hidden:0x4399870 type: hidden name: UPFLG value: ]}
   >}>
```

And `javascript:yoyaku` function like:

```
function yoyaku(wkobj,wkvalue,wklnk){
    var wkurl = '';

    // jump to here
    if (wkvalue != '' && document.links[wkobj].disabled != true){
        for (cnt = 0; cnt < document.links.length; cnt++){
            document.links[cnt].disabled = true;            
        }

        // return 'https://example.com/xyz/logon.asp?LINK=showmenu'
        wkurl = wklnk + 'logon.asp?LINK=showmenu';

        window.open(wkurl,'SisetuReserveIac','location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1024,height='+(screen.availHeight)+',top=0');

        for (cnt = 0; cnt < document.links.length; cnt++){
            document.links[cnt].disabled = false;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I expect when I click `Click link` above, I'll get a page with 2 frames in new window like that:

```
<frame src="menu.asp" name="menu" frameborder="0" noresize="">
  ...
<frame>

<frame src="top.asp" name="contents" frameborder="0" noresize="">
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="top.asp">
    ...
  </form>
<frame>
```

Currently, I use `mechanize` get url that we have in `javascript` function, like:

```
agent.get("https://example.com/xyz/logon.asp?LINK=showmenu")
```

But, i get page have only 1 frame like :

```
[1] pry(#<Crawler::Inzai>)> agent.page
=> #<Mechanize::Page
 ...
 {frames #<Mechanize::Page::Frame "menu" "menu.asp"> #<Mechanize::Page::Frame "contents" "top.asp">}>
```

Can you help about it?
Can I use `Mechanize` for this case?
Many thanks!

Comment: i dont think mechanize runs any javascript, you'll have to use a headless browser like phantom/selenium for that.

Comment: You can search script tag in page like `agent.page.search("script")[1]`